# Why do we use "did" in simple past with every person but we use "do" or "does" in simple present?

Tags: etymology

Do you have any idea why we use *do* and *does* in simple present and only *did* in simple past? I mean why there is only one form in simple past but there are two forms in simple present.

And one more question: why is the sentence "*He goes to school*" simple present? In this sentence there is no sign of present, so why do we call it simple present?

My question is why we use *did* in simple past with every person but we use *do* or *does* with different persons in simple present.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "past definite" and "present indefinite". If you could use a more general term, it would be really helpful.

Comment: you are lucky that in English you have to learn only two forms of the verb to do in simple present tense (do, does) , and only one in simple past tense (did).
In Latin you would have to learn six for present tense and another six in past tense.

Comment: We had more forms, but we lost them over time.  It happened naturally and not by design.

Comment: Languages aren't created by "grammarians" sitting down and making a list of rules. They evolve over time, and with use.

Comment: Just to complement @snailplane here's how *"do"* was conjugated in Old English [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_grammar#Anomalous_verbs)

Answer (score 4):

In general, grammarians don't make the rules for people to follow, they find the rules describing what people *do* with the language.

Although I cannot really make out what your specific problem is, my best guess at an answer is

> because the people that were speaking the language long before you were born, and probably most of them after you will be dead, use the language in that way.